# Why are these two determinants equal?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants, enumerative-combinatorics

This question is a follow up on Mark Wildon's comment from [an earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322894/determinantal-symmetry-proof-requested-part-i).

As usual, let $(q)_k=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)$ with $(q)_0:=1$. Also, define the Gaussian polynomials by
$$\binom{n}k_q=\frac{(q)_n}{(q)_k(q)_{n-k}}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is there a **conceptual reason** why the two determinants are equal?
> $$\det\left[q^{-ai-bj}\binom{i+j+a+b}{i+a}_q\right]_{i,j=0}^{c-1}
> =\det\left[q^{i^2+j^2-ij}\binom{i+j+a+b}{i+a}_q\right]_{i,j=0}^{c-1}.$$

**Remark.** An algebraic proof is not requested because I know how to.

Comment: Could it be some Lindström-Gessel-Viennot type count in both determinants?